# How to validate a email id in java?

Tags: java

I want to validate email id which is entered by the user.
In my program the constraints are that there cannot be whitespaces,(-),(_) and more than one (@).
This is the code i have written but its not giving the right output.
the code is:

```
import java.io.*;
class test
{
void main() throws IOException
{
 BufferedReader    br=new BufferedReader(new     InputStreamReader(System.in));

       System.out.println("Enter your email-address");
      String emailid=br.readLine().trim();
     boolean ans=true;
     int n=0;
     while(ans)
     {
         for(int i=0;i<emailid.length();i++)
         {
             char temp=emailid.charAt(i);
             if( Character.isLetterOrDigit(temp)==false && temp!='@' && temp!='.')
             {
                 System.out.println("A email id can consist of only alphabets,numerics and '.'");
                 emailid=br.readLine().trim();
                 ans=true;
                 continue;
                }
                 else
            {
                ans=false;

            }
                 if(temp=='@')
                 {
                     n+=1;
                    }
                    if(n>1)
                    {

                 System.out.println("email id can have only one @..Please try again");
                 emailid=br.readLine().trim();
                 ans=true;
                 continue;
                }

            else
            {
                ans=false;
            }

        }
    }
```

}
}

Comment: use regex. validate just the form, or also the address itself?

Comment: I want to validate only the email address.

Comment: yes, but validate the form, or also it's existence? if it's just it's form, use regex